# TechGraph: The landscape of a tag/tech in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, third-party, external-project

I built a website https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/ which can provide an overview/landscape of certain tech (tag) in Stack Overflow. (will be extended to all sites in Stack Exchange)

Given a tech (tag), the website can render:

- its definition from tagwiki;
- its asking trend in Stack Overflow;
- its knowledge graph i.e., visualizing related tech and their relationships in an interactive graph so that you can have an overview of it;
- experts of it with their knowledge graphs rather than a list of tags.

Given multiple tech/tags, they will be compared in both asking trend and knowledge graph.

In addition, you can also specify a task and a programming language to see a knowledge graph which may provide some hints or solutions to the tasks.

Hope that you can enjoy the exploration journey.

### Screenshots

[image]

### Update

**Version 0.1**

- Right-click to see the tagWiki (there was a collision between single click and double click);
- Add one section (ExpertGraph) to show the expertise graph of experts who have earned more than 3,000 reputation scores before March 8th, 2015 in Stack Overflow. Some experts are not shown as their answer number is insufficient to generate an expertise graph;
- Adjust the UI layout;
- Add one "beta" icon from testing applications.

**Version 0.2**

- Add a new function that users can look up top-upvoted questions for the given tag;
- Add a new function that users can look up tag-related external links which is mined from post content from Stack Overflow;
- For some tags, you can also find related code snippets mined from tagWiki and [Rosetta Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA6uM.png);
- Speed up the page loading by optimizing both front-end and back-end code.

**Version 0.3**

- Extract the tag category label from tag wiki in Stack Overflow;
- Discriminate the library/API/toolkit from the knowledge graph and put them aside the knowledge graph in the website so that users can have a clearer view.

### Problems

- What other features do you want?
- Any suggestions to improve existing ones?
- Is it good for Stack Exchange to adopt our features?

For any questions, bugs, suggestions, please leave a message in this post.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to post an app on Meta - that's what [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) is for.

Comment: And it seems that you've already posted [this on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/questions/6569/techgraph-a-landscape-of-a-tag-tech-in-stack-overflow) too. Meanwhile, if you want to promote this on SE, you can try to put it on your "About Me". Just wait for some time for the feedback/feature-request. PS. great site!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I am wondering if the features in my own website can be adopted for Stack Exchange, i.e., tag graph replacing a list of tags,  so I ask a question here and hope to get some suggestions.

Comment: Asking trend x axis doesn't seem to display correctly (tried d3.js)

Comment: @RobertLongson I checked it in Stack Exchange Data Explorer but did not find the mistake. You may check it in [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/359571#graph)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but as the very first comment here says, this is off topic here.